# Why isnt my Random array returning random values?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

Okay, so essentially, what I want to do is create and print an array of 100 random numbers. My attempts seem to be failing... instead of getting 100 random numbers, I seem to be getting numbers put in order from 0-99. Can someone explain how I can resolve this issue, please? Much appreciated.

```
public static void enterRandom()
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to the random number generator and arranger!");
    System.out.println("Now, watch me generate 100 random numbers, and print them in order...");
    System.out.println("...");
    System.out.println("...");
    System.out.println("...");

    Random what = new Random ();
    int[] store = new int [100];

    for (int i = 0; i <= store.length; i++)
    {
        store[i] = what.nextInt(100); //not in random?
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    return;
}
```

}

Comment: *System.out.println(i);* - You are printing the counter.

Comment: Print the array instead of the counter System.out.println(store[i]);

Comment: 1. You're printing the wrong thing, 2. `return` is redundant, 3. `i <=` will not end well. The fact that (3) didn't cause an exception raises suspicions to me that you didn't run the code, and are merely asking questions for the fun of it.

Comment: @Bathsheba or that they did and for now ignored the exception

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: I do hope so.

Comment: @Bathsheba I am getting an error but I chose to fix the typo from before first. Can you explain why it's an issue please (if you don't mind)?

Comment: @navysoul: The designers of compilers and runtime libraries practically give up their lives in order to issue instructive error messages. Would you kindly share the actual error with us?

Comment: @Bathsheba My apologies... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
        at arrays100.enterRandom(arrays100.java:26)
        at arrays100.main(arrays100.java:9)

Answer (score 2):

As all of the comments have stated, you are printing the variable `i`, instead of the current index in the array. So, replace `System.out.println(i);` with `System.out.println(store[i]);`

To fix the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception, replace `for (int i = 0; i <= store.length; i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i < store.length; i++)`

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but usually we don't answer questions where the solution is something like a typo. I don't agree with closing it for that reason, but that may explain the downvotes. Also, the answer is already in the comments (as you state) so people may think you answered for farming easy karma.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I see. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: That's up to you, I guess. Anyone else wants to chime in about this?

Comment: I downvoted as the answer is not useful to the OP since you don't address the array bounds exception. IMHO there's nothing wrong with snatching comments to form an answer.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I downvoted because trying to get credit for an answer that others have already provided is plagiarism.

Comment: @pjs I didn't plagiarize anything. I simply indicated that other comments have already mentioned that. Also, none of the other comments mentioned how to fix the problem.

Comment: @Bathsheba My bad, I didn't run the program so I didn't noticed the exception. I edited the question to fix that.

Comment: Yes, you did.  Look up the definition of the word, it does **not** mean copying verbatim.  Your answer provided no new info relative to the comments *that you noted* at the time I downvoted.  Your edit addresses a different error that was pointed out by others after you had already answered.

Comment: @pjs Plagiarism: the practice of taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own. Nowhere did I do anything like that. Also, my edit addresses the same error as everyone else.

Comment: With this answer, you're seeking credit (karma) for what BackSlash and eric.v had already pointed out in comments.

Comment: @pjs Well, they didn't post it as an answer, so I took the initiative to post it myself. I could have completely copied their answer and not even mentioned them. I don't know of any SO rules against this. Feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks! Fake internet points are important to a healthy lifestyle.

Comment: And they help the peer review process ;-)